# How to use DLNA screen casting on Android 4.4 (api19) version?

Tags: android, android-tv, dlna, cling

I am working on Android TV development, and the requirement is for my app to act as a DLNA receiver, receiving DLNA screen casting from mobile video apps. I found a project, https://github.com/devin1014/DLNA-Cast, which meets my needs, but its minSdk version is Android 7.0. Once I change it to api 19, it throws an error:

```
5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :dlna-dmc) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.4.2, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=android, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
         > No variants of org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016 match the consumer attributes:
             - org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016 configuration runtime declares a runtime of a component:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'orbit' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar'
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about asm-transformed-variant (required 'NONE')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.2')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-desugaring (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation (required 'false')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-is-debuggable (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-min-sdk (required '23')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :dlna-dms) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.4.2, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=android, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
         > No variants of org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016 match the consumer attributes:
             - org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016 configuration runtime declares a runtime of a component:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'orbit' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar'
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about asm-transformed-variant (required 'NONE')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.2')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-desugaring (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation (required 'false')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-is-debuggable (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-min-sdk (required '23')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :dlna-core) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.4.2, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=android, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
         > No variants of org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016 match the consumer attributes:
             - org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016 configuration runtime declares a runtime of a component:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'orbit' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar'
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about asm-transformed-variant (required 'NONE')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.2')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-desugaring (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation (required 'false')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-is-debuggable (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-min-sdk (required '23')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
```

How can I resolve this exception? Or are there any other projects that can fulfill my requirements?